# Difference between "forementioned" and "aforementioned"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I am writing a scientific article, and the reviewer has pointed out that I should check the typo "forementioned", which I use several times in the paper. I would like to know,  is there any difference between "forementioned" and "aforementioned"? Should I use "aforementioned" instead?

Comment: The word is actually aforementioned.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forementioned%2Caforementioned&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cforementioned%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caforementioned%3B%2Cc0), I would avoid *formentioned*. It's infrequently used today and it's not in
some online and desk dictionaries I've checked. The Ngram nicely shows that  two words began to diverge in frequency about 1850. I think that most readers, like your reviewer, will think you forgot the *a*.

> foremention v.
>
> To mention beforehand
>
> Deriviates
>
> **forementioned** adj.
>
> Previously mentioned OED

> Alternative form of **aforementioned**  [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forementioned)

> **aforementioned**, adj. and n.
>
> Previously mentioned, esp. in a text.  OED

---

> I think there's as much likelihood that Willy can be rehabilitated as
> there is that the **forementioned** people can be. [Peg Tittle;
> *Just...Think about it!*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Just_Think_About_It_2nd_edn/CIBJEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=forementioned&pg=PT322&printsec=frontcover)

> ... including all the **forementioned** services relating to ...
> [*Australian Official Journal of Trade Marks*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Australian_Official_Journal_of_Trade_Mar/CvT11Ym_0CkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=forementioned&dq=forementioned&printsec=frontcover)

> The forenamed accused, Antoinette, was brought from the
> **forementioned** prison personally into the presence of the foresaid Vice Inquisitor. [P. G. Maxwell-Stuart; *Witch Beliefs and Witch
> Trials in the Middle Ages*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Witch_Beliefs_and_Witch_Trials_in_the_Mi/1jzDDwL0g28C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=forementioned&pg=PA159&printsec=frontcover)